# getting all substrings between two parameters with php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function that gets all the substrings between two parameters.
so far i have been unsuccessful in achieving this.
this is my current code.

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){


    $times = substr_count($string, $start) -1; 
    $storedsubstrs = array(); 
    foreach(range(0, $times) as $number){ 
        $ini = strpos($string, $start); 
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) + strlen($end); 
        $storedsubstrs += array($number => trim(substr($string, $ini, $len))); 
        $string = substr_replace($string, "", $ini, $len); 
    }

    return $storedsubstrs; 

}

$fullstring = '{{ IMPORT header.html %}}

{{ FOR %}}
s
{{ ENDFOR %}}

{{ IMPORT footer.html %}}';
echo "<pre>";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '{{ ', ' %}}');

print_r($parsed);
```

but this is not working it is outputting

```
Array
(
[0] => {{ IMPORT header.html %}}
[1] => {{ FOR %}}
s
[2] => {{ ENDFOR %}}

{
[3] => { IMPORT footer.html %}}
)
```

the output i am trying to get is

```
 Array
(
[0] => {{ IMPORT header.html %}}
[1] => {{ FOR %}}
[2] => {{ ENDFOR %}}
[3] => {{ IMPORT footer.html %}}
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$fullstring = '{{ IMPORT header.html %}}

{{ FOR %}}
s
{{ ENDFOR %}}

{{ IMPORT footer.html %}}';
$re = '/{{(.*?)%}}/';
$str = '{{fgdfg%}}';

preg_match_all($re, $fullstring, $matches );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: why dose this not work if i change the {{ and %}} to {{ FOR %}} and {{ ENDFOR %}}

Comment: I don't understand. can you type new string here?

Comment: please add code above on question so it is in proper format

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution

```
<?php
function substrs_between($start, $end, $string){
    $arrayhold = array();
    $loopammount = substr_count($string, $start) - 1;
    foreach(range(0, $loopammount) as $count){

        if(isset($my_start_pos)){
            $my_start_pos = strpos($string, $start, $my_start_pos + strlen($start));
        } else {
            $my_start_pos = strpos($string, $start);
        }
        if(isset($my_end_pos)){
            $my_end_pos = strpos($string, $end, $my_end_pos) + strlen($end);
            $my_end_lenth = $my_end_pos - $my_start_pos; 
        } else {
            $my_end_pos = strpos($string, $end) + strlen($end);
            $my_end_lenth = $my_end_pos - $my_start_pos;
        }


        $arrayhold[$count] = substr($string, $my_start_pos, $my_end_lenth);
    }
    return $arrayhold;
}

$mystr = "{{ FOR }} sompthing {{ ENDFOR }} {{ FOR }} sompthing2 {{ ENDFOR }}";
$my_start = "{{ FOR }}";
$my_end = "{{ ENDFOR }}";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(substrs_between($my_start, $my_end , $mystr));
```

you can change $my_start and my $my_end to anything and it will get a sub string between them

Answer (score 0):

I elaborated a bit on the reply by Hanan F, on how to get all substrings between a first and a second tag. Basically, I included the possibility to in- or exclude the markers in the reply. Up to now, you could only get the reply With the markers.
Some error checking might be useful before taking this function really public - for instance: does marker1 come before marker2, and if not, what happens? But for a reliable source the following should work:

```
<?php
$yourstart = "1";
$yourend = "2";
$yourstring = "Lots of 1 things 2 happen between 1 and 2. I don't remember if 1 as well as 2 are prime, 1 maybe not, but 2? Dunno.";

echo "<br>First with markers:<br>";
echo $yourstring;
$some_ar = substrs_between($yourstart, $yourend, $yourstring, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($some_ar);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<br>And now without the markers: <br>";
$some_ar = substrs_between($yourstart, $yourend, $yourstring, false);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($some_ar);
echo "</pre>";

$your2start = "<b>";
$your2end = "</b>";
$your2string = "A lot of <b>bold</b> in <b>this</b> sentence. Better <b>I get rid of it.</b>";
echo "Text between markup tags:";
echo "<br>" . $your2string ."<br>";
$some_ar = substrs_between($your2start, $your2end, $your2string, false);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($some_ar);
echo "</pre>";

function substrs_between($start, $end, $string, $withmarkers) {
$arrayhold = array();
$loopamount = substr_count($string, $start) - 1;
foreach(range(0, $loopamount) as $count) {

if (isset($my_start_pos)) {
    $my_start_pos = strpos($string, $start, $my_start_pos + strlen($start));
} else {
    $my_start_pos = strpos($string, $start);
}

if (isset($my_end_pos)) {
    $my_end_pos = strpos($string, $end, $my_end_pos) + strlen($end);
    $my_end_length = $my_end_pos - $my_start_pos;
} else {
    $my_end_pos = strpos($string, $end) + strlen($end);
    $my_end_length = $my_end_pos - $my_start_pos;
}

if ($withmarkers) {
    $arrayhold[$count] = substr($string, $my_start_pos, $my_end_length);
} else {
    $arrayhold[$count] = substr($string, $my_start_pos + strlen($start),  $my_end_length - strlen($start) - strlen($end));
}   
}
return $arrayhold;
}
?>
```